# Ethernaut Delagation Problem

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I tried to hack the `Delegation` contract using this `hack` contract but this doesn't seem to work. I went over other solutions which do similar things in the console by calculating the function signature of the `pwn()` function and sending a transaction with the signature hash in the `data` section.

The below code is also supposed to do the same thing but it is not transferring the ownership to my address.

Can somebody explain?

```
contract Hack{

    function hack(Delegation _add) public returns (bool) {
        (bool result, ) = address(_add).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("pwn()"));
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is right, but it is your contract claim the ownership not you. The goal is to claim the ownership for your address so you need to send the transaction from you address.

Comment: Yeah! lol, my bad.